Building OpenDKIM with other SignatureAlgorithms
As the title suggests - how would I build OpenDKIM from source to use signing algorithms other than the default ?
Previously, I had a postfix server correctly set-up with opendkim signing my emails. This was done using the APT package manager to install opendkim.
For customisability and other reasons, I am trying to install opendkim from source. I followed the same process as for the APT case but when I run:
./opendkim -A -p inet:12301@localhost -x /path/to/file.conf

The syslog shows:
opendkim: verifier mode operating without rsa-sha256 support; terminating

I have tried setting the conf variable SignatureAlgorithm to be rsa-sha256 but this returns the same error.
I have checked the supported algorithms of my installation with:
./opendkim -V

which returns:
rsa-sha1

So, how can I either:
a) build opendkim with rsa-sha256 support?
b) build opendkim with another signing algorithm support that will allow me to encrypt mail?
I have read elsewhere online that opendkim has been without support for a number of years. Ideally, I would like a solution using opendkim, as I am already familiar with it.
As mentioned above, I previously had opendkim working only several months ago, when installed via APT. I assume this to therefore be possible with a custom installation.
Help is greatly appreciated.
Update
As a work around, I have used the version of OpenDKIM provided by the apt package manager. I run this binary as:
/usr/sbin/opendkim -p inet:12301 -x /path/to/opendkim.conf

Postfix is able to interact with opendkim, and my mail receives a sha-256 hash.
Running /usr/sbin/opendkim -V, I see the apt package manager OpenDKIM version is 2.11.0.
Searching for the source code of this version, I find it on github.com under a directory Pre-Releases.
I download, configure and make opendkim version 2.11.0. Again, the error 'cannot begin verifier mode as sha-256 is not present' prevents functioning.
My overall question remains.
However, a possible stepping stone, if someone can explain; how does one know in what manner the apt version is configured, such that, for the same underlying OpenDKIM version, the above performance difference is realised ?
